# Where to store binary files in a Node.js project?

Tags: node.js, express, binaryfiles

I have a 100MB .BIN file that I need to read repeatly in almost every request in a Node.js project (structured by express-generator).

Where is the recommended/correct place to store it?

Comment: I would just store it along your entry file. I would also read it into memory on startup, and never read it again. Its going to cost 100MB of RAM, but that is significantly less than the time to read 100MB for every request.

Comment: Since you are reading it on startup, it might be worth it to to fs.readSync, that way you don't have to worry about waiting for it to be buffered into memory.

Comment: can i ask what this file does? Im curious why someone would need to do this, there might be a better alternative

Comment: Its a BIN file that associate ip's with countries. Any recommendation/alternative about this method?